# Dask worker out of memory but I don't know why

Tags: python-3.x, dask

I have a dask cluster with several workers each with 93 GiB = 100 GB memory, and the total cluster has more than 2 TiB of memory (see picture below). When I watch the dashboard as my job runs, it fluctuates a bit but always looks like something shown in the picture, i.e. no where near the memory limit. Then, one of the workers will die due to an out-of-memory error. What I am really baffled with is how did it happen and why is it not shown at all in the dashboard? (note my dask version is new enough that it shows unmanaged memory as light color for each worker).
[image]

My task is to load a relatively large dataset defined on a 2D grid (a wavefield). First, I would like to filter it in the time domain (which means accessing the entire time axis for each point at once). Then, I would like to write the filtered data for all points at each single time to a separate file. When these two tasks are by themselves(i.e., if I only filter the data without writing; or if I don't filter the data and just write the raw wavefield), dask works very well. However, when they are combined, the OOM error occurs for large simulations (but still works fine for small simulations).

The raw wavefield data (variable: `wave_on_slice_channel`) for my large simulation is 11.67 GiB.

[image]

For a smaller test simulation (which works when the above two tasks are combined), it is only 20.75 MiB.

[image]

My (simplified) code are as follows:

```
### Function to filter
def filter_wavefield(pos, butter_filter):
    filtered = signal.sosfilt(butter_filter,wave_on_slice_channel[pos,:].compute()).astype("float32")
    return filtered

### Function to write files
def save_filtered_wavefield(chunk):
    # Many lines omitted here for setting up the write
    filtered_data = ncfile.createVariable('filtered_data', np.float32, ('data','time')) 
    filtered_data[:,:] = blocks[chunk].compute()
    ncfile.close()
    return

### Putting multiple points together into a dask bag to avoid crushing the scheduler
coord_list = [i for i in range(nelem*ngll)]
coord_bag = db.from_sequence(coord_list,npartitions=100)
coord_bag = coord_bag.persist()
wait(coord_bag)

### Submitting tasks for filtering
### and converting back to dask arrays 
filtered = coord_bag.map(filter_wavefield, butter_filter)
filtered_waves = filtered.compute()                                              # this is a numpy array
filtered_da = da.from_array(filtered_waves,chunks=wave_on_slice_channel.chunks)  # this should be exactly the same in size and shape as the raw wavefield, except this is filtered
blocks = filtered_da.to_delayed().ravel()                                        # Split filtered wavefield by the raw wavefield's original chunks so each writer only sees a portion of the whole wavefield.
```

The above code always works fine no matter for the small or large simulations (because this is just one of the two tasks, i.e. filtering + writing). As a check, `filtered_da` for the small simulation is shown, and we can see it is exactly the same as the raw wavefield from the small simulation (except the number of graph layers, which I think is just the number of operations it took to get this dask array and so not important?)

[image]

The **problem comes now**  when I want to save these filtered data to files. I have something similar as above:

```
### Use dask bags to avoid too many tasks
file_list = [i for i in range(len(blocks))]
file_bag = db.from_sequence(file_list,npartitions=len(blocks))
file_bag = file_bag.persist()
wait(file_bag)

### Write out expected number of files to receive 
### This file is always written so up to here everything is fine.
with open(dest_dir+'/NOF.txt','w') as f:
    f.write("The number of expected filtered data files is: %d" % len(blocks)+'\n')

### Submit tasks to write files
### This is where things break
for i in range(len(blocks)):
    f.append(client.submit(save_filtered_wavefield,i)).
```

Note the variable passed to each call to `save_filtered_wavefield` is simply an index `i`, and then within that function the data is accessed with `blocks[i].compute()`. I think this is fine because the filtering also has `wave_on_slice_channel[pos,:].compute()`.

I have tried to delete some variables from memory, especially the persisted `coord_bag`, but the problem persists. I have also tried to read some articles about managing memory on dask, but since I can't seem to see anything on my dashboard, I am still quite lost here.

Sorry for the long post, but any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: As a brute force fix, I tried to double the memory on each worker to 200 GB, yet the problem remains. I checked `sacct -u $USER -j $JOBID --format=MaxRSS` and the largest memory is indeed ~202 GB so one worker did go OOM. I am very baffled as to what is causing this as this is several times larger than the data set I work with. Could this be my mis-usage or some kind of internal bugs???

Answer (score 0):

More detailed answers will follow hopefully.

My first thought: it is a bad idea to access the global dask array within a function to be submitted. You should call the high level API (like array, bag) in the client only, and write functions that work on the partitions only (numpy arrays). You should never normally be calling `compute()` on a worker.

Comment: I see. I thought the opposite that it is bad to pass in actual (large, even for a partition) numpy arrays into workers and calling `compute()` too early. I will give your suggestion a try!

Comment: That's bad too! Look at actual workflows with arrays - dask should be doing the job of passing chunks around, not you.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me again! However, now I am actually pretty confused. I thought I should only pass in parameters for the worker functions, as seen [here](https://examples.dask.org/applications/embarrassingly-parallel.html#Using-the-Futures-API) under _Using Futures API_. I thought this is worthwhile to open a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74662292/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-access-large-dask-arrays-in-functions-submitte) now about how to make a worker function that works on a user-defined slice, such as `data[i,:]`, of data.

Comment: My old approach would be to just use the `i` as the parameter and `data` as a global dask array, which to my surprise maybe causing me this current OOM issue.